# text overflow on skew div containers

Tags: html, css

currently I use `clip-path` for containers that should be skew.

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
}

#first {
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 100% 0%, 100% 80%, 0 100%);
}

#second {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
}

#spacing {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="box">
  <p>
    first container with a very very very long text. It's really long and won't fit here. Some text may disappear when the screen size gets smaller.
  </p>
</div>

<div id="spacing">
</div>

<div id="second" class="box">
  <p>
    second container with a longer text
  </p>
</div>
```

If the window gets smaller the text will not break into a new line it will just disappear.

How can I make the missing part of the text appear in the next line?

You can find an example of what I want to do on this page

https://www.thenativeweb.io/#

Comment: at the end you used clip path :p ... the issue is that I previously used the line-height to center one line of text, but there is more way to vertically center text (in the link I have shared)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe below approach solves your issue. I deleted defined `height` and `line-height` for `#box`, and added `padding: 30px 0`, so to make some space to clip. Now text acts more naturally. You can adjust precise values.

```css
.box {
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

#first {
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 100% 0%, 100% 80%, 0 100%);
}

#second {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
}

#spacing {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="box">
  <p>
    first container with a very very very long text. It's really long and won't fit here. Some text may disappear when the screen size gets smaller.
  </p>
</div>

<div id="spacing">
</div>

<div id="second" class="box">
  <p>
    second container with a longer text
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"If the window gets smaller the text will not break into a new line it will just disappear." - problem is coming because of line-height of box class and have to remove height:150px from box class.

```css
.box {
  height: auto;
  line-height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 80px 20px;
}

#first {
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 100% 0%, 100% 80%, 0 100%);
}

#second {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
}

#spacing {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="box">
  <p>
    first container with a very very very long text. It's really long and won't fit here. Some text may disappear when the screen size gets smaller.
  </p>
</div>

<div id="spacing">
</div>

<div id="second" class="box">
  <p>
    second container with a longer text
  </p>
</div>
```